# remove all chars in string before a name

Tags: c#, string, char

How can I remove all chars in a string until a certain name is matched? For example, I have the following string:

```
"C:\\Installer\\Installer\\bin\\Debug\\App_Data\\Mono\\etc\\mono\\2.0\\machine.config"
```

How do I remove all chars before the string '`App_Data`'?

Answer (score 6):

```
var str = @"C:\Installer\Installer\bin\Debug\App_Data\Mono\etc\mono\2.0\machine.config";

var result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("App_Data"));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

prints:

```
App_Data\Mono\etc\mono\2.0\machine.config
```

Well, kind of fancy way of doing this is to try to use platform independent class [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx), which is designed to handle file and directory path manipulations. In your simple case first solution is better in many factors and consider next one only as an example:

```
var result = str.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
                .SkipWhile(directory => directory != "App_Data")
                .Aggregate((path, directory) => Path.Combine(path, directory));

Console.WriteLine(result); // will print the same
```

Answer (score 0):

Or implemented as extension method:

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static string TrimBefore(this string me, string expression)
    {
        int index = me.IndexOf(expression);
        if (index < 0)
            return null;
        else
            return me.Substring(index);
    }
}
```

and to use it like:

```
string trimmed = "i want to talk about programming".TrimBefore("talk");
```